# What can we say about these random variables i.d or i.i.d?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose there are 100 students on a class and we have noted down their heights. The heights of the students are distributed such that 10 are 5.0 feet 10 are 5.1 feet 10 are 5.2 feet ......10 are 5.8 feet and 10 are 5.9 feet.So the distribution os uniform.

We take two random variables X and Y as the heights of any two students.
So if we see the distribution of X and Y they will be same as the distribution of the class. But if we pick a student for X then the distribution for Y changes.

So are these random variables i.d or i.i.d? And would this answer change if we change the number of students in class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in this situation you pick out one by one two students and denote their lengths by $X$ and $Y$ respectively then $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

However the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ will **both** be uniform on the set $\{5.0,5.1,\dots,5.9\}$.

The fact that $Y$ corresponds with the student chosen as second does not change that.

In order to grasp that try to think of any reason why the second student should have a larger (or smaller) chance to have length $5.4$ than the first. You will search for that in vein.

Quote: "If we pick a student for X then the distribution for Y changes..."

Here you are not talking about the (original) distribution of $Y$ but of the distribution of $Y$ under conditions like e.g. $X=5.4$.

Comment: Loved your explanation!

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

There is some confusion here regarding random variables.

If you view the class as $100$ realizations $\lbrace X_1, \dots X_{100} \rbrace$ of a uniform variable $X$, then it might very well be that the sequence $\lbrace X_i\rbrace$ is iid. But that cannot be inferred from just by looking at the sample - it depends on your assumptions about $\lbrace X_i \rbrace$.

If, on the other hand, you define $X$ as a random draw without replacement from the finite population represented by the class, then consecutive draws are clearly not $iid$ (although they are $id$ - see drhabs's answer).